# ExampleComponent.vue none colouring

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed npm and node js to my laravel project and i can't see colouring in my code.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Code without colouring
[image: Code without colouring]

Comment: Do you use any extension for vue?

Comment: You mean syntax highlighting. What editor/IDE are you using?

Comment: Sublime text. No highlighting.

Comment: Did either of the below answers solve your problem? If so, please will you mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Install Vue Syntax highlighter extension in your Editor.
If you are using vscode install vetur extension.
Your code editor seems to be sublime text. You can try this https://github.com/vuejs/vue-syntax-highlight  for sublime text

Answer (score 0):

you have to install `Vue Syntax Highlight` package .

- Via Package Control: search for `Vue Syntax Highlight`.

your vue component will looks like this [image]